# Simulate dataTransfer for drag events in TypeScript

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, drag-and-drop

I am writing unit tests for a drag and drop interaction that relies on the `dataTransfer` of the event. Also I am using typescript. To simulate the event(s) I wrote this little function:

```
function createDragEvent(eventName: string, dataTransferData?: Array<any>) {
    const event = new CustomEvent(eventName, { bubbles: true, cancelable: true });
    event.dataTransfer = {
        setData: jasmine.createSpy("setData() spy"),
        getData: jasmine.createSpy("getData() spy").and.callFake(function() {
            return dataTransferData[0] === 'text/plain' ? dataTransferData[1] : undefined;
        })
    };
    return event;
}
```

However, TypeScript tells me

> TS2339: Property 'dataTransfer' does not exist on type 'CustomEvent'.

I cannot *not*  use the `dataTransfer` and I cannot use native `DragEvent`s because I cannot set the data or spy on its functions. Is there a way to deal with this, e.g. tell TypeScript that `dataTransfer` is ok or disable the error for this file or something like that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Could you do something like this?

```
const event: CustomEvent & { dataTransfer?: DataTransfer } =
    new CustomEvent(eventName, { bubbles: true, cancelable: true });
```

Comment: YES! Thank you! In the end I had to do `CustomEvent & { dataTransfer?: any }` but your method worked!

Comment: It would be great if you'd explain the syntax

Comment: The type `CustomEvent & { dataTransfer?: DataTransfer }` is a type that has everything on `CustomEvent`, and also an optional field `dataTransfer` which could be of type `DataTransfer ` or be missing.

Answer (score 39):

If anyone comes here like I did because the `Event` object in TypeScript does not have a `dataTransfer` attribute:

Just use `DragEvent` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting an `undefined` error when I try to access `DragEvent`. Using @libertyernie 's answer I was at least able to create an event parameter which served my purposes.

Comment: I've also been able to use `sinon JS` to stub the `DragEvent interface` provided by `jsdom`. 
e.g. `const fakeEvent = sinon.stubInterface<DragEvent>();`

Answer (score 1):

If you are like me and cannot use the `CustomEvent` solution because your function is expecting a `DragEvent` the following worked for me:

```
    const dragEvent = new DragEvent('test')
    const mockEvent = {
        ...dragEvent,
        dataTransfer: new DataTransfer()
    } as DragEvent
```